# spreadsheet find multiple matches

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet for runners with multiple pages

[image: Van and runner information]

I'm trying to automatically calculate the total mileage for each runner (in columns D an H in the Vans sheet) depending what legs that runner is assigned from the Legs sheet.

[image: Leg breakdown]

This was working fine since each runner was only going to be running in a predefined range, so my initial formula in the vans sheet worked. But now I need to move runners around into different blocks and I'm trying to find a more general formula that can figure this out w/out saying only find this runner in the three ranges I defined.

**So my question is**:  Is there a forumula that can use on the Vans sheet, that will take that runners name - then look through and find all matches in the Legs sheet (column D) - then add up the distance (column G) for those matching rows?

ie: in my 2nd picture of (Legs sheet), runner 1 is in cell D2 and D20, so his total mileage would be 5.53 + 4.1  = 9.63 . (G2 + G20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the various ***IFS functions built into Excel (which ones you have available depends on your Excel version):

SUMIFS
COUNTIFS
AVERAGEIFS
MAXIFS
MINIFS
Those might fit your needs.

Comment: worked:  =SUMIFS(Legs!$G$2:$G$42,Legs!$D$2:$D$42,A2).  Example for Runner 1

Answer (score 0):

In Google Spreadsheets you can use arrayformula sumif to sum the runners.

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A<>"",sumif(Legs!D2:G,A2:A,Legs!G2:G),""))
```